# setVisible in Table in libgdx not working?

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx

I have the following problem:

I am trying to implement a menu with submenus in libgdx, using the table layout. When a submenu is clicked, a listener is fired, which should setVisible(false) the previous menu, and setVisible(true) the new one. But, although I successfully display the new one, the previous one is still here! Could someone help me?

Here is my code:

The Menu.java:

```
public class Menu extends Table {
  private Stage stage;

  public void attachToStage(Stage s) {
    if (s != null) {
      stage = s;
      s.addActor(this);
    }
  }

  public Menu() {
    this(null);
  }

  public Menu(final Stage s) {
    attachToStage(s);
    setFillParent(true);
    top();
    left();
  }

  private void addButtonWithListener(String label, ClickListener listener) {
    add().width(10);
    Label l = new Label(label, SkinManager.get());
    add(l).width(100);
    row();
    if (listener != null)
      l.addListener(listener);
  }

  /**
   * @param label
   * @return The menu, for chaining
   */
  public Menu addButton(String label) {
    addButtonWithListener(label, null);
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * 
   * @param label
   * @param m
   *          the menu to add
   * @return The main menu, for chaining
   */
  public Menu addMenu(String label, final Menu m) {
    addButtonWithListener(label, new ClickListener() {
      @Override public void clicked(InputEvent e, float x, float y) {
        System.out.println(getChildren());
        setVisible(false);
        m.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
    m.attachToStage(stage);
    m.setVisible(false);
    return this;
  }
}
```

My Application:

```
public class TestApplication implements ApplicationListener {
  private Stage stage;

  @Override public void create() {
    stage = new Stage();
    Menu m = new Menu(stage).addButton("Move").addButton("Stay");
    m.addMenu("Attack", new Menu().addButton("Sword").addButton("Bow"));
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
  }

  @Override public void render() {
    stage.draw();
  }
   // Other empty methods
}
```

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Problem was unrelated, see my answer

Comment: try ((Widget)e.getTarget()).setVisible(false); instead of setVisible(false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the problem: not related at all to the Table, just forgott to clear the screen in the Application.

I just added

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

in the render function.